# Android 128GB micro SD does not show up in Windows 11

Tags: sd-card, windows-11

I have a Motorola Moto G7 Supra with a 128GB SD card. The USB port is broken. I tried to put the SD card in an adapter and it did not read or recognize it. I have a 32GB card that reads in the adapter fine but not this 128GB Android SD.

Is there a way to install an app on Windows 11 that can read the SD card from the Android using the SD card adapter?

I tried searching but come up with only "use USB connection" which I don't have.

Comment: try [linux](https://rufus.ie)

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Sorry, the site discourages sending files to personal email (as well as everyone's email address being kept secret from anyone for privacy and spam prevention).

Comment: An 128GB SD-card is most likely formatted with exFAT file-system which is supported by Windows 11. If you can not read it most likely the sd-card was adopted as internal storage and is encrypted and thus only readable by the phone itself.

Comment: ok if that exFAT is true i should be able to read it.  i always kept it as external and did not install apps to run on it

Comment: i have a linux machine thanks

Comment: ok.  is there an emulator app for windows that can read the internal storage of an android phone?  internal storage is not a secret storage system is it?  sure doesn't stop hackers if they want to get into your stuff.

Comment: Internal storage isn't a secret but encryption is and for good reasons. That said there can be another problem which is an old SD/MMC reader that doesn't support cards of that size,

Comment: Ok UPDATE: I "operated" on my USB port on the Android Phone and using a pin and a box cutter razor blade , i was able to straighten the pins out and get the phone to charge.  
i can connect the usb cable directly to the Windows 11 computer, but, still cannot read the SD card in the android phone.
I tried everything from ip address access to Wi-Fi network even an app called Anydesk and that app can actually access the phone but access is denied when i try to transfer files 
so th phone can be accessed, but cannot see it in windows any other way so far.
Bluetooth says paired but wont access

Comment: i will try to get a reader that can handle 128gb sd cards next.  anyway i would like to fix connectivity still

Comment: Update - went to look at SD Card readers and only categorized by speed.  No mentions anywhere that there is a size limitation or even mentions that.